# how to create a horizontal scrollbar in SAP-ui5 using xml or Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

```html
 <content>
            <ScrollContainer width="100%" horizontal="true" vertical="true" focusable="true">
             <HBox id="idHBox"  width="99.9%"/>
            </ScrollContainer>
        </content>
```

this is my code in the XML site , HBox is a Parent element includes a SVG element 
but the Problem that it just show the vertical scrollbar but the horizontal not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the absolute size of your Image?

Here is a small example.

If you change the Image width, the horizontal scrollbar appears/disappears (e.g. width: "100%")

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" 
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"></script>
        <script>
            var app = new sap.m.App();
            var oImage = new sap.m.Image({
                width: "3000px",
                height: "300px",
                src:"https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/alphachannel.svg"        
            });
            
            var oHbox = new sap.m.HBox({
                width: "100%",
                items : [oImage]
            });
            
            var oScroll1 = new sap.m.ScrollContainer({
                width:"100%",
                focusable:true,
                vertical:true,
                horizontal:true,
                content : [oHbox]
            });

            var page = new sap.m.Page({
                content : [oScroll1]
            });
            
            app.addPage(page);
            app.placeAt('content')
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="content" class="sapUiBody">
    </body>
</html>
```